# jQuery wait till all page animations are done

Tags: jquery, animation, promise

I know how to wait till an animation is done with

```
$('#element').animate(speed,function(){
//code here
});
```

and with multiple elements with

```
$('#element1, #element2').promise().done(function(){
//code here
});
```

but how do I wait till **all** of the elements on the page are done animating? I would much rather not just put in every element that I'm waiting for in there.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To select everything that's being animated currently, just do `$(":animated")`
http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

Combining that with what you already have there, it'd just be

```
$(":animated").promise().done(function() {
    //code here
});
```

Answer (score 10):

The answer given by Jeremy T works fine - although based on the comments on the jquery site he linked (http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/), it would be a faster solution to  add a class to each element on the page that may be animated, and then select them using

```
    $('.animationclass').filter(':animated').promise().done(function() {
//Your function
});
```